# Postgres 9.2 select star into an array

Tags: debugging, select, row, postgresql-9.2, stringification

I want to do something like this inside a stored procedure so I can see the result of an insert statement for debugging:

```
thing := array_to_string(ARRAY(select * from some_table limit 1 ));
raise info 'insert result: %',thing;
```

Where all the columns of some_table get concatenated into an array

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are of uniform type. You can't have an array where different entries have different data types.

What you appear to want is an anonymous row (record).

```
DECLARE
    debug_row record;
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT 1 INTO debug_row;
    RAISE INFO 'insert result: %',debug_row;
```

Note that this only works for a single row result. For multiple rows you can call the query as the input for a loop and iterate over the result. There are examples in the PL/PgSQL documentation.